# Excel Macro VBA: Double click to tick issue

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, double-click

how can I make the double click works ONLY when column 1,2,3 and 4 have values? I don't know where I should insert the code.. it's something like if column 1,2,3 and 4 have values then doubleclick.enable = TRUE else doubleclick.enable= FALSE..

Kindly need advice. My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 6, 13
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F13, M2:M13")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True

        Target.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        If Target = "" Then
            Target = ChrW(&H2713)
        Else
            MsgBox "You cannot modify the cell."
        End If

        End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am asking just to clarify the issue.
You only want to call doubleclick procedure if any cell in column 1 to 4 have value
Or you want to check if corresponding row has value?

for option 1, you may use

```
If Application.CountA(Range("A1:D" & Rows.Count)) > 0 Then
    'Your Code
End If
```

for second option

```
If Application.CountA(Range("A" & target.Row & ":D" & target.Row)) > 0 Then
    'Your Code
End If
```

I tested above codes but in case of any mistake, we can modify them

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I want the value in column F and M based on my codes. For example,  F3 and M3 to call double click for tick only when ALL column A to D have values. If let's say A3, B3, C3 have values except D3, then there should be no result in F3 and M3 when double clicked. Either one cell blank in column A to D should disable double click in column F.

Comment: 2nd option works but with one issue. It works when either A3,B3,C3 or D3 is filled, then F3 shows tick when double clicked. I want it to be when all A3:D3 are filled, then only proceed to show tick in F3 when double click. Either one missing in A3:D3 should stop F3 to produce result.. that's what I mean.. I'm sorry if I'm still not clear enough with my words.

Comment: Application.CountA(Range("A" & target.Row & ":D" & target.Row)) =4 works for you

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally got it! What if I need to key in similar function but different column? How will the code look like?

Comment: If your columns are consecutive then you can change to A and D letters to E to H or whatever you want but if the columns are not consecutive then you have to specify the range with nested cells

Comment: Yes. it works like a treat. I have one more question.. I have searched almost everywhere in google to disable cut/copy/paste function but to no avail, their codes did not work at all. My version is 2010. Kindly need your advice/help.

Comment: You want to prevent user to select a range at workseet. Am i right?

Comment: More specifically, preventing user to cut, copy and paste any cell contents to another cells. So I need to write a code to block cut/copy/paste function in this workbook.

Comment: For cut and copy, it is kinda easy compare to paste. You can use
If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Or Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Comment: For Paste, you have to trigger the Excel that some data has been added. The best way I can think that you can prevent users by using environ function. You can use below code in thisworkbook object. This prevents users to paste anything if they activate your workbook.
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
If Environ("UserName") <> "Please Write Your UserName" Then
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub
By last, if you are ok to enter a password for everytime for yourself, the best option is protect your workbook with password with ThisWorkbook.Protect "Password"